# How to strip html tags from markdown without messing with links

Tags: html, ruby-on-rails, markdown, sanitize

I want to `sanitize` the following markdown in my Rails application:

```
<iframe>
<b>Title</b>
**Bold**
<http://example.com>
```

#### Exptected Result:

```
Title
**Bold**
<http://example.com>
```

#### Actual Result

Using the rails helper `sanitize` I get the following result where the `<http://example.com>` is stripped, because it seems to be considered a html tag:

```
Title
**Bold**
```

#### Question

How can I sanitize the text without interfering with the Markdown markup

Comment: @dbugger, the `<http://example.com>` syntax used by the OP is fully supported by Markdown. You can read about it in the [Automatic Links section in the documentation](https://daringfireball.net/projects/markdown/syntax#autolink).

Comment: You should probably be sanitizing the HTML output, not the Markdown input. For a detailed explanation see [Markdown and XSS](https://michelf.ca/blog/2010/markdown-and-xss/).

Comment: @Waylan: I disagree, I am using Markdown because I do not want any HTML in the input.I want to for example remove `<a>` tags in the input but allow markdown links, they will not be distinguishable in the resulting HTML. So I need to sanitize _before_ processing the Markdown.

Comment: @Besi if you're trying to secure submissions (against XSS) from untrusted users, then the only way is to filter the output. But if you're trying to accomplish something else, then that's different. I assumed the former because why would you care otherwise? If the output is indistinguishable, then why would it matter?

Comment: @Waylan It makes sense to me to pre-sanitize the part of the system that stores the markdown template, and having trusted data in there first.

Comment: @Besi the current markdown implementations do have a filter that sets aside html blocks, and you could customize that code to just leave it as omitted, including perhaps allowing link tags.

Comment: @zanlok you can certainly strip out raw HTML from Markdown, but that doesn't address XSS concerns. You **still** need to sanitize the Markdown output for the reasons in the link I point to above. If you have to do that anyway, then why bother with stripping the raw HTML beforehand? That only limits your user's legitimate use of raw HTML.

Comment: Indeed. The only sensible advice is to mostly worry about the render target. Wanted to also respond to the question intent, though, which could apply to lots of destination outputs. Cuz in one instance we wanted only raw text Markdown templates in the db.